# Making words in formula narrower

Tags: math-mode, scaling

I am using this snippet:

```
\(PSE = 1- POFOD\)
```

which results in this:

[image]

Which is pretty stretched out. How do I make this narrower ?

Comment: math italic is designed to make a product of variables not look like a word so never use it for multi-letter identifiers, use `\mathit{PSE}` or `\mathrm{PSE}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example (MWE), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\mathrm{PSE}` works out perfectly for me, thank you, post an answer I'll accept

Comment: you might also benefit from this: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

math italic is designed to make a product of variables not look like a word so never use it for multi-letter identifiers, use `\mathit{PSE}` or `\mathrm{PSE}`